# wso2 api manager nginx You will be redirected to /publisher/services/auth/login then oauth2/authorize?response

Tags: wso2-api-manager

After config nginx, it try to redirected to /publisher/services/auth/login that faild with <>oauth2/authorize?response .........
could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

If you use loadbalancer like nginx, update callback url like following and restart server.

```
regexp=(https://api.am.wso2.com/publisher/services/auth/callback/login|https://api.am.wso2.com/publisher/services/auth/callback/logout)
```

Also

I set the config of following file to defult, and my problem fixed .

`/wso2am-.2.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/public/config/settings.js –`